# What's the dimensionless form of an expression with temperature?

Tags: temperature, dimensional-analysis

I'm trying to get a dimensionless form of the following expression:

\begin{equation}
\delta (T) = a_{\delta} \left(\frac{1}{T}\right)^{b_\delta} + c_\delta ~,
\end{equation}

so that the numerical values of the parameters ($a_{\delta}, {b_\delta}, c_\delta$) are independent of the selected system of units for temperature ($K$, $^o C$, etc.) [see Barenblatt, "Scaling", Cambridge Texts in Applied Mathematics, 1st ed. (2003)].

In fact, if I include a reference temperature, $T_0$, the expression above tends to be more consistent, but the first parameter $a_\delta$ still depends on the numerical value of the coefficient $(T_0 / T)$. The resulting expression will be:

\begin{equation}
\delta (T) = a_{\delta} \left(\frac{T_0}{T}\right)^{b_\delta} + c_\delta ~.
\end{equation}

Is better to perform a substraction of temperatures, given that a substraction between two temperatures in Celsius and Kelvin have both the same result? i.e.:

\begin{equation}
\delta (T) = a_{\delta} \left(\frac{T_0}{T-T_0}\right)^{b_\delta} + c_\delta ~.
\end{equation}

Note that $\delta$ is dimensionless.

Comment: What is the dimension of $\delta(T)$?

* Note that the 2nd form, based on $\frac{T_0}{T - T_0}$, is _not_ a correct choice, since it produces a (artificial) singularity at $T = T_0$ which was not in the original expression.

Comment: Excuse me for imprecise definition of the problem. $\delta (T)$ is the shape parameter of a Gumbel distribution function and is adimensional. In the problem, this parameter depends on temperature. It is absolutely correct the consideration about the singularity in $T - T_0$. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that the $\delta$ has the dimension of $\delta_0$; i.e., $ [\![  \delta ]\!] = [\![ \delta_0 ]\!] $.
Then, we can rewrite the relation (in simplified notation),
$$ \delta(T) = a \, (\frac{1}{T})^b + c ~,$$
as
$$ \delta_0 \, \frac{\delta(T)}{\delta_0} = a \, \frac{1}{T_0^b} \,(\frac{1}{T/T_0})^b + c ~, $$
or
$$ \frac{1}{\delta_0} \,\delta(\frac{T}{T_0}) = \frac{a}{\delta_0 \, T_0^b} \,(\frac{1}{T/T_0})^b + \frac{c}{\delta_0} ~. $$

If we denote dimensionless variables by a tilde, 
$$\begin{align}
\tilde{\delta} &:= \frac{\delta}{\delta_0} ~, \\
\tilde{a} &:= \frac{a}{\delta_0 \, T_0^b} ~, \\
\tilde{c} &:= \frac{c}{\delta_0} ~,
\end{align}
$$
we'll obtain the dimensionless form of the relation,

$$ \tilde{\delta}(\frac{T}{T_0}) = \tilde{a} \, (\frac{1}{T/T_0})^b + \tilde{c} ~. $$

Note that $b$ must be dimensionless itself, since it is a power.

Furthermore, the second suggestion, based on $\frac{T_0}{T - T_0}$, is not valid since it artificially produces a singularity at $T = T_0$ which did not exist in the original expression.

Comment: @AdriánÁlvarez-Vázquez : Thanks for accepting the answer.
For numerical calculations, it is usually better to rescale the parameters to some known relevant scale in the system; this makes them dimensionless and gives their magnitude a proper (relative) meaning.

Comment: Thanks newly for the suggestion. Is there any book on Scaling and Self-Similarities would you recommend? I usually use Barenblatt G. I. bibliography.

Comment: @AdriánÁlvarez-Vázquez : That book is good enough, I suppose; even far beyond what you'd need every day.